# Cassandra DataStax OpsCenter 5.2.2 doesn't show disk info (empty storage)

Tags: cassandra, datastax, opscenter

In the test cluster dashboard, it is shown that all agents are connected. However, the storage capacity sub-graph shows zero bytes. [The captured picture of OpsCenter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QMmVu.png)

There is no problem with writing and reading in cql or DevCenter. The Cassandra version is 2.2.4. Does it have relationship with .yaml file?

Comment: What version of cassandra?

Comment: Any errors in your agent.logs?

Comment: @phact Yes, but I couldn't understand what do these errors mean. For example: _There was an error when attempting to load stored rollups.
 clojure.lang.ExceptionInfo: throw+: {:type :opsagent.cassandra/keyspaces-does-not-exist, :message "The OpsCenter storage keyspace, \"OpsCenter\", does not exist yet."}_

Comment: @phact Another frequently appeared error is : _Error while initailizing backup service
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No implementation of method: :make-reader of protocol: #'clojure.java.io/IOFactory found for class: nil
 at clojure.core$_cache_protocol_fn.invoke(core_deftype.clj:541)
 at clojure.java.io$fn__8551$G__8546__8558.invoke(io.clj:73)
 at clojure.java.io$reader.doInvoke(io.clj:106)
 at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:410)_

Comment: 1) Did you check if the keyspace exists? If it doesn't, there will be a corresponding error message in the opscenter.log when it failed to create it. You can restart opscenterd to try again or try the create statement manually. 2) The backup service should not affect your metrics.

Comment: @phact, the keyspace "OpsCenter" dose exist when I typed in _desc keyspaces_　and _desc keyspace "OpsCenter"_

Comment: @phact, By the way, I uninstalled cassandra from my computer (win7) before and reinstalled datastax cassandra on this computer.

Comment: You have to start opscenterd service once before the agents to create the keyspace abs initialize everything

Comment: @ChrisLohfink Could you please tell me how to start opscenterd service once before the agents? Do I need to restart the cluster?

Comment: The opscenter daemon (the webui) creates the opscenter keyspace. Something is strange if that is running, showing metrics (which are stored in that keyspace) yet the agent is reporting error "OpsCenter does not exist". I am guessing the problem for the disk graphs lie more in windows 7. OpsCenter doesn't really support windows as a first class citizen. Its a "best effort" but theres likely to be bugs. The disk/os metrics are one of those things that probably doesn't work in all versions of windows.

Comment: @ChrisLohfink I installed Cassandra on another clean computer (also Win7), Opscenter works well. You are right, Windows is not the first class citizen to Opscenter. I think I had better to wait and see if a new version of Datastax Cassandra and Opscenter could fix my problem.